# How to search in rad file explorer for current folder including sub folders

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to use filter in rad file explorer which needs to search current directory including sub folders items.Currently i can search in only main folder but not sub folders items using built in filter box.Some body help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not available OOB because it is likely to cause performance issues. Nevertheless, you can create such functionality yourself:

1. Implement a custom **FileSystemContentProvider**, overriding the **ResolveDirectoryAsTree()** and **ResolveDirectory()** methods in the way, described in this help article: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/fileexplorer-custom-filebrowsercontentprovider.html
2. Call **recursively** the **ResolveDirectoryAsTree()** and **ResolveDirectory()** methods from your content provider in order to take references to all listed files and folders (e.g.  base.ResolveDirectoryAsTree()). Once you gather all the needed data to one place you can make a search through the items in it. Despite of the accuracy of such an implementation, note that this information-gathering would be a slow process, and you might meet performance issues.

You can find more detailed information regarding the custom commands in the following help article: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/fileexplorer-add-custom-button-context-menu-item.html

There may be other ways to get this done, but I do not know them.

Comment: Thanks but as we have large list of folders and sub folders we dropped this requirement for Performance issues