# RadFileExplorer Multilevel Filter (Search)

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radfileexplorer

Anyone has an answer to this question:

**[How to search in rad file explorer for current folder including sub folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24323703/how-to-search-in-rad-file-explorer-for-current-folder-including-sub-folders)**

**How Can I get RadFileExplorer Filter to search for all files including subfolders.**

Any Help.

Comment: I don't have idea but you require something [like this](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/fileexplorer-custom-filebrowsercontentprovider.html)

Comment: Yes. It's Required. Explorer needs a search with it. other wise it's useless for a client

Comment: I've replied to the other thread. Perhaps you can consider voting up the original one instead of creating duplicates

Comment: I will see what If I an get it to work using a Custom FileSystemContntProvider as you mentioned in the other thread. I will get back to you. thanks :)